# Can't erase digits from c++ string by using the 'erase' function

Tags: c++, string

Using c++ 14.
I'm prompting the user for a string containing both letters and integers, and trying to "strip" the integers from the string itself via the string.erase() function.

The problem i'm facing is when there are 2 or more sequential numbers, than the function seems to erase the first but delete the latter.

**Example:**

```
   input: H23ey Th2e3re St01ack O34verflow
   output: H3ey There St1ack O4verflow
```

I can do it another way by using a new string, looping through the existing one and adding only what isalpha or isspace, but it seems messier.

**code:**

```
string digalpha {};
cout << "Enter string containing both numbers and letters: ";
getline(cin, digalpha);


for (size_t i {}; i < digalpha.size(); i++)
    if (isdigit(digalpha.at(i)))
        digalpha.erase(i,1);


cout << digalpha << endl;

cout << endl;
return 0;
```

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [Debugging Guide](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/)

Comment: Pay extra attention to the fact that your changing the size of the string when you are iterating it.

Comment: Also pay attention to the fact that when you remove element [i] something else takes its place.  What if that something else is another digit?

Comment: Take a piece of paper. Write down a three-digit number. Cross out the first digit. The result is a new number. Cross out the second digit *in the new number*. The result is a still newer number Cross out the third digit *in the newer number*. Did it work? What was the result?

Comment: What would happen if you processed the string in reverse order?

Comment: Here: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2223b8816751b346

Comment: @nathanoliver i'm a few lesssons away from debugging according to my course so ill wait with it although i know it's a really powerful tool.

Comment: @Nix Look at HolyBlackCat's link.  Whether you're ready to use a debugger, you **are able** to use `std::cout`.

Comment: @n.m I think that cleared it alot for me. That leads me to a second solution i had before - initializing a second string and reading only letters and spaces to it.

Comment: If there are two consecutive digits, erasing the first will cause the second to be shuffled to where the first was.    So you need to change the `if (isdigit(digalpha.at(i))` to `while (i < digalpha.size() && isdigit(digalpha.at(i)))`

Comment: @Nix Or you could do `i--;` when erasing a character.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat That was extremely helpful, gave me insight on how to manually debug my code to the future also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first sentence you were writing that you are using C++14.

In "more modern" C++ the usage of algorithm is recommended. So normally you would not use C-Style For loops.

The standard approach that you can find everywhere, is a combination of `erase` with `std::remove_it`. You will find this construct in many many examples.

Please consider to use such a solution instead of a for loop.

You can even include the output in an algorithm using `std::copy_if`.

Please see:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

int main()
{
    std::string test1{ "H23ey Th2e3re St01ack O34verflow" };
    std::string test2{ test1 };

    // C++ standard solution for erasing stuff from a container
    test1.erase(std::remove_if(test1.begin(), test1.end(), ::isdigit), test1.end());
    std::cout << test1 << "\n\n";

    // All in one alternative
    std::copy_if(test2.begin(), test2.end(), std::ostream_iterator<char>(std::cout), [](const char c) { return 0 == std::isdigit(c); });

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If there's two digits next to each other, it skips the second digit. This happens because the index, `i`, keeps going up, even though everything got shifted over:

```
for (size_t i {}; i < digalpha.size(); i++)
    if (isdigit(digalpha.at(i)))
        digalpha.erase(i,1); //Here, i goes up anyway, skipping character after digit
```

To fix this, we just have to decriment `i` after erasing a digit:

```
for (size_t i {}; i < digalpha.size(); i++) {
    if (isdigit(digalpha.at(i))) {
        digalpha.erase(i,1);
        i--;
    }
}
```